# How to use a custom React hook to make a POST or DELETE request with Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, axios

I am trying to make a generic useAxios hook in React. I would like to be able to import this hook into other components to make Get, Post, and Delete requests. I have created the hook and it works fine for making Get requests, but I am stuck on how to make it work for Post/Delete requests.

The issue is that I would be making the Post/Delete request when a user clicks a Save or Delete button, but I cannot call a React hook from an event handler function or from useEffect.

Below is the generic hook I created:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export interface AxiosConfig<D> {
    method?: 'get' | 'post' | 'delete' | 'put';
    url: string;
    data?: D;
    params?: URLSearchParams;
}

export const useAxios = <T, D = undefined >(config: AxiosConfig<D>) => {
    
    const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState<T>();
    const [isLoading, setIsloading] = useState(true);
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const controller = new AbortController();
        const axiosRequest = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios({ ...config, signal: controller.signal })
                setResponseData(response.data)
                setIsloading(false);
            } catch (error) {

                setIsError(true);
                setIsloading(false);
            }
        }

        axiosRequest();

        return () => {
            controller.abort();
        }
    }, [config.url, config.method, config.data, config.params])

    return {responseData, isLoading, isError}
}
```

And this is an example of a component where I would like to make a Delete request

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import { useAxios } from '../../api/hooks/useAxios';

export interface IItem {
    title: string;
    info: string;
}

export default function Item() {
    const { id } = useParams<{id?: string}>();

    const {responseData: item, isLoading, isError} = useAxios<IItem>({
        method: 'get',
        url: `http://localhost:3000/items/${id}`
    })

    const handleDelete = () => {
        //not sure what to do here. Need to make DELETE request

    }

    return (
        <div>
            {isLoading && <p className='loading'>Loading...</p>}
            {isError && <p className='error'>Could Not Load Item</p>}
            {item && (
                <>
                    <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                    <p>{item.info}</p>
                    <button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</button>
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I could just make the axios request directly in the Item component and not use my useAxios hook, but then I would end up repeating code throughout the application.

Comment: You are on a good path trying to reduce redundancy, but, I wouldn't recommend plugging your API requests throughout your components as this will lead less-redundant but API-tighed components. You are better using the recommended approach of handling your requests at the store level and may be having a general purpose action creator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `DELETE` route is the same as the `GET` route, you'd just store the method type in a local state variable and change it:

```ts
const { id } = useParams<{id?: string}>();
const [method, setMethod] = useState('get');

const {responseData: item, isLoading, isError} = useAxios<IItem>({
  method,
  url: `http://localhost:3000/items/${id}`
});

const handleDelete = () => setMethod('delete');
```

However, I think you will realize that this only solves part of the problem, which is that you have tightly coupled your component's return JSX with the response type of the `GET` request (`IItem`).

Comment: Thank you, that does work for deleting the item!

Is it considered bad practice to couple a component's JSX to an API response? Would it be better to make the API call eslewhere and pass the result to the component as a prop?

Comment: If the component doesn’t really serve a purpose without the fetched data, then it’s more idiomatic to fetch higher up and pass as props.